# Unconfirmed and rejected transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, coinomi

I am quite new to the Bitcoin world. About 1 BTC was sent from my Electrum wallet to my Coinomi wallet, with 0.5 mBTC per kB commission, and it remained unconfirmed for about 50-60 hours. Then [the transaction was rejected](https://blockchain.info/tx/503e7733cc3520aae46a4edf9e79a587668dcc094b3d20f9fa8744acdf9efb51).

Yet the amount  is still reflected as "unconfirmed" in my wallet. 
Two questions: 
1. What can I do about the "unconfirmed" amount. 
2. What did I do wrong and why it was rejected after all? 
Please help

Comment: seems to be a blockchain fork

Comment: And what can I do?

Comment: check the sender address to be sure that the coins are still there and try again

Comment: How exactly can I do it in my Electrum wallet please?

Comment: search for the public address at blockchain.info

Comment: If I just want to keep this amount in the wallet, will it finally add up to my total balance as currently my total balance is shown without this  sum?

Comment: Yes, if the transaction is rejected, the transacted sum should remain on the original address. If it is not appearing it could be a synchronizing delay of your Electrum. If you want to see the actual and up to date balance of an address, always check it on a blockchain explorer like blockchain.info.

Comment: thanks, yet a day after the rejection I am still waiting and can't regain the access to all my funds.

Comment: @neptune: It doesn't have anything to do with a blockchain fork. 50 satoshi/byte is just not a high enough fee currently.

Comment: So how many satoshis is the sufficient commission and how can I fix the issue with the unavailable funds in my wallet please?

Comment: Hm, now I've noticed the update by the administrator. Now my transaction is still shown as unconfirmed but again in the list of transactions waiting for confirmations on blockain.info. So it was rejected and then automatically accepted again? I think bc and the corresponding software have a lot of work ahead to do make it more user-friendl

Answer (score 3):

Bitcoin network is heavily loaded with thousands transactions staying unconfirmed for a long time, your funds are totally safe with Coinomi.
Your transaction will eventually get confirmed or it will be "discarded" by the blockchain network and your funds will be back in your wallet. 
Unfortunatelly, there is nothing we can do to unstuck your tx.
To avoid such issues in the future you could increase the default fees for Bitcoin from Settings -> Transaction Fees.

You could also use a transaction accelerator such as https://www.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/ or https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2204426.0

You could find more information about bitcoin fees through the link : https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

Coinomi Support

Comment: Thanks, however currently the issue is that the transaction has been rejected but my funds are still (24 hours after the rejection) shown as an "unconfirmed" transaction in my Electrum Wallet. I understand that now it is not an issue of Coinomi wallet yet I have no idea how long it will take to  regain the access to my funds.